# Scala - Importing libraries for parsing JSON - PredictionIO

Tags: json, scala, predictionio

I have problem importing libraries

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
```

```
[ERROR] [Console$] [error] /home/lavalamp/PredictionIO/algorithms/bestseller/src/main/scala/DataSource.scala:25: object api is not a member of package play
[ERROR] [Console$] [error] import play.api.libs.json._
[ERROR] [Console$] [error]             ^
[ERROR] [Console$] [error] /home/lavalamp/PredictionIO/algorithms/bestseller/src/main/scala/DataSource.scala:26: object api is not a member of package play
[ERROR] [Console$] [error] import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I suppose "import play.api.libs. json._ import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._" are in different lines. Have you the play plugin in project/plugins.sbt?

Comment: PredictionIO uses json4s a lot for json parsing so it's already in the runtime artifact. You might take a look at that, I've used it before.

Comment: Also you have to add either to the build.sbt for templates, what does your's have in it?

Comment: Dear Pat, This is my build.sbt,    import AssemblyKeys._

assemblySettings

name := "predictionio-bestseller-algorithm"

organization := "com.biglabs"

parallelExecution in Test := false

test in assembly := {}

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "io.prediction"    %% "core"          % pioVersion.value % "provided",
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core"    % "1.4.1" % "provided",
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib"   % "1.4.1" % "provided",
   "org.scalatest"    %% "scalatest"     % "2.2.1" % "test"
)

Comment: Dear Pat, I already added "org.json4s"     %% "json4s-native" % "3.3.0", thanks.